# Is function from module

Tags: python

I have a function that accepts the operator and two arguments 
Need to restrict this function to condition argument only from the module operator

```
import operator

def check(condition, a, b):
    # some code to check is condition from operator module
    return condition(a,b)

check(operator.eq, 1, 1)
```

Comment: please clarify what `cond` is precisely.

Comment: You could possibly check for the `__module__` property of the function that's passed in, and if it's `_operators` then it's one of the functions from there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:

```
assert condition.__name__ in dir(operator), 'operator_func must be from operator module'
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator` is a `module` object, and it has a `__dict__` containing all of it globals.
If `cond` is an attribute of the `operator` module, then

```
cond in vars(operator).values()
```

must be true, and false otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose there's no way to do that.
You can only verify input parameters in a function. Just verify `a` and `b` internal `operator.eq`.